# 3D Cardioid, using equations

Tags: mathematics

I'm trying to create a 3D [Cardioid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardioid), for which I would like to control/adjust the thickness along the axis perpendicular to the cusp. Do I use the cardioid's parametric equations for X and Y? What about Z? I'm getting "Error Evaluating Expression."

Comment: Need more details about your setup…

Comment: If you get an error, show us the error and the code/driver expression which produces the error. Best would be the blend file itself https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Cardioid with Geometry Nodes

I was able to make a basic cardioid using Blender's Geometry Nodes by following the parametric equations for X and Y on the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardioid)

[image: Cardioid Curve in Blender with Geometry Nodes]

1. Add a new `Geometry Nodes` modifier to the default cube.
2. Add a `Curve Circle` node and connect it to the `Geometry` output. Increase the `Resolution` to get a smoother curve.
3. Insert a `Set Position` node after the `Curve Circle` node.
4. Use a `Spline Parameter` node to get the angle around the unit circle. The `Factor` output gives `0.0` to `1.0` where `1.0` represents a full turn. We want a full turn to be `2 * pi` so add a `Multiply` node after the `Factor` output. You can type `2 * pi` and Blender will recognize that. I'll call this parameter *t* from now on
5. Use `Math` nodes to to set up simplified parametric equations for `X` and `Y` $$x(t) = 2\cos t - \cos 2t$$ $$y(t) = 2\sin t - \sin 2t$$
6. Combine `X` and `Y` with a `Combine XYZ` node and plug that into the `Position` input of the `Set Position` node.

### Controlling Width

A `Multiply` node can be added after the calculation for x(*t*) to make the whole curve wider along the axis where the cusp sits. This is effectively introducing *a* back into the parametric equation. $$x(t) = a(2\cos t - \cos 2t)$$

[image: A wide Cardioid Curve in Blender with Geometry Nodes]

### The Z Dimension

Without a specific description of how the final 3D Cardioid should look it's hard to give guidance, but a cool way I found to bring the `Z` dimension into it was to add nodes for $$z(t) = \sin t$$ and then mess with the `Multiply` nodes on the Spline Parameter Factor.

[image: Cardioid in Blender with Geometry Nodes with Z dimension considered]